# Can Box2D be configured to conserve total energy of the system?

Tags: physics, box2d, physics-engine

**What I want**

I want a physics engine that can support a few dozen balls and polygon objects interacting with each other in a closed environment. It needs to support objects rotating after collision. It needs to support fixed objects (infinite mass). The total energy (sum of kinetic and potential of all objects) should be roughly constant (with an error of <1% after 30 seconds of simulation).

I am thinking about using Box2D in my game, but is Box2D "accurate" enough to do that?

**Example of what I want**

I wrote [this example of bouncing balls](https://redmoncoreyl.github.io/bouncingBalls/). The balls just keep going and going because I designed the collisions to conserve energy. Can Box2D do that but with polygon collision and rotational energy?

Comment: Nothing in games is accurate. It's all sleight of hand, smoke and mirrors. We find ways to cheat just enough to get something that looks plausible, even if we're using the dirtiest approximation under the hood. I'd suspect there's a way to achieve the gameplay outcomes you want without running an expensive engineering-grade simulation, but to help you with that we'll need to know more about the gameplay that this energy conservation requirement is serving.

Comment: @DMGregory Right, I understand that. Even the example I gave in OP is a bit hand-wavy. If you go to https://redmoncoreyl.github.io/bouncingBalls/, you see that the initial conditions are random, but every frame after that, there is no apparent loss of energy in the system, even after running for a long time. The balls just keep going and going. That is because I designed the collisions to conserve energy. Can Box2D handle that, even with all the complexity of arbitrary polygons and angular velocity?

Comment: Will you get that automatically in every circumstance? No, emphatically. Can you engineer circumstances to approximate that to within your game's needs? Quite likely. But to help you get "conserved-enough" energy, we need to know what situations arise in your game and what this conservation is needed to support.

Comment: @DMGregory Specifically: up to a couple dozen balls and polygons interacting and colliding in a closed environment. Some fixed objects (infinite mass). Supports rotating objects. The total energy (sum of kinetic and potential of all objects) should be roughly constant (with an error of <1% after 30 seconds of simulation).

Comment: Make sure to edit your question to include those specifics, then we can clean up this comment thread. The rotating polygons will likely be the biggest challenge, since as you noted balls have an analytical solution to within float accuracy.